# Can variables in VB.Net Linq query be used as method call out/byref parameter?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've just found a bug in my code because I assumed that variables declared in the Linq query (via Let keyword) are not set when used as out (byref) parameters when calling a method within the query.
Does anyone know if this valid only for VB.Net or is it also valid for C#? 
Is this documented somewhere?

The MSDN documentation for the Let keyword states:

> Computes a value and assigns it to a new variable within the query.

The documentation later on states:

> The Let clause enables you to compute values for each query result and reference them by using an alias.

Here is the example of my code which fails:

```
From c In Me.AllContractsInHourBlock
Let isForcedFullTrading As Boolean = False
Let noTradingReason As ContractNoTradingReason = ContractNoTradingReason.None
Let targetMode = c.CalculateTradingMode(instant, sendWarningMessageOnNoPrognosis, isForcedFullTrading, noTradingReason)
Select New With {
   .CurrentMode = c.TradingMode,
   .TargetMode = targetMode,
   .TradingModeChanged = (c.TradingMode <> targetMode),
   .IsForcedFullTrading = isForcedFullTrading,
   .CurrentNoTradingReason = c.NoTradingReason,
   .NoTradingReason = noTradingReason,
   .NoTradingReasonChanged = (targetMode = ContractTradingMode.NoTrading AndAlso c.NoTradingReason <> noTradingReason
```

In the code sample above the variables noTradingReason and isForcedFullTrading will always end up as initially assigned when the Select New is reached.
If I extract the variables outside the Linq then everything works fine.

```
Dim isForcedFullTrading As Boolean = False
Dim noTradingReason As ContractNoTradingReason = ContractNoTradingReason.None      
From c In Me.AllContractsInHourBlock
Let targetMode = c.CalculateTradingMode(instant, sendWarningMessageOnNoPrognosis, isForcedFullTrading, noTradingReason)
Select New With {
   .CurrentMode = c.TradingMode,
   .TargetMode = targetMode,
   .TradingModeChanged = (c.TradingMode <> targetMode),
   .IsForcedFullTrading = isForcedFullTrading,
   .CurrentNoTradingReason = c.NoTradingReason,
   .NoTradingReason = noTradingReason,
   .NoTradingReasonChanged = (targetMode = ContractTradingMode.NoTrading AndAlso c.NoTradingReason <> noTradingReason
```

Here is the the signature of CalculateTradingMode method:

```
Function CalculateTradingMode(instant As DateTimeOffset, sendWarningMessageOnNoPrognosis As Boolean, ByRef isForcedFullTrading As Boolean, ByRef noTradingReason As ContractNoTradingReason) As ContractTradingMode
```